# Screenshot.png Not displaying on admin

Tags: wordpress, themes, admin, screenshot

I have installed a premium theme and changed the screenshot.png and uploaded it via ftp, upon looking at the admin panel it still display the old screenshot.png and the link it was linking was

`http:// www. mysite .com/wp-content/themes/mytheme/screenshot.png`

and if I directly go to the link

`mysite.com/wp-content/themes/mytheme/screenshot.png`

it shows my new screenshot but not showing on my admin panel, why does the admin panel detects the screenshot with www and if I look on my hosting file manager my theme has the new screenshot. I've tried to delete and reinstall wordpress from scratch including the theme but still doing the same thing. any thoughts?

Thanks!

Answer (score 10, accepted):

It's probably cached. Try CTRL+F5 or clear browser cache and see if that helps.

A quicker solution is to add a query arg to the end of the url, like `?refresh=1` which would make your browser think it is a different URL, even if the query arg doesn't do anything. This won't fix the original issue until your cache clears, still, but it will tell you that it is working (at least for other people who haven't seen the old version yet).

Comment: wow thanks, I've tried clearing cache and it doesnt work, but ctrl+f5 did it, wow, didnt know something like that until now. Thanks @radGH I thought at first clearing the cache and cookies would do but no luck so I've reinstalled the entire site didnt know something like it. thanks again

Comment: Cache is also browser specific, so you can also try a different browser. or if you have chrome, incognito mode uses a cleared cache each time it is opened. The only thing that is really difficult to clear are favicons, lol. glad it's fixed for you though.

Comment: I already did that, used incognito and firefox but no luck, but the ctrl+f5 did, if I only knew it lol it would save me a lot of time. Thanks! yes favicon is also stucked lol but I have plugin to remove it. thanks

Comment: In my case, screenshot.png wasn't updating. CTRL + F5 worked.

Comment: Yeah! It's grate Idea

Comment: in my case open the dev tools help.

Comment: That would work too, particularly if you have "disable cache" checked under the Network tab

Answer (score 0):

Just to give prominence to the solution I ultimately had to use in Firefox:

1. Open *Developer Tools*
2. Open *Settings* (keyboard shortcut F1)
3. Under *Advanced Settings*, enable **Disable HTTP Cache (when toolbox is open)**
4. Reload page

credit: [Shmulik](https://stackoverflow.com/users/7270134/shmulik) and [Radley Sustaire](https://stackoverflow.com/users/470480/radley-sustaire) for mentioning it in the comments on the previous answer

Answer (score 0):

If you are using the latest version of WordPress, some changes may have been made to the code. If you are unable to update the screenshot.png, here are some tips you can apply to display the theme screenshot

1. You can **hard refresh** the browser
   *Hold down Command, Shift, and click the ‘R’ key* On Mac
   *Hold down Ctrl and press F5* On Window
2. **WordPress** has added the Version in the screenshot URL So you need to define the version in the style.css file

   ```
   Theme Name: TEST
   Author: The team
   Author URI: https://wordpress.org/.
   Requires at least: 5.3
   Tested up to: 6.4
   Requires PHP: 5.6
   Version: 2.1
   ```
3. You can directly change the path of the url by overreiding the code in the wp-admin panel .

   ```
   Go to the wp-admin 
   Open theme.php
   Search class "theme-screenshot"
   ```